# Radio button group name is not working in editorfor with postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, razor, radiobuttonlist

I have a List of object to display on the screen, I am using "EditorFor" for it. 
But in this object I have a radiobutton which user can select and then click on submit button to postback.

The user can only select one item, So i defined the name attribute in the list like

```
 @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Matched, true, new { Name = "name1" })
```

But now when the form is postback **I can't see any radio button selected**. The matched property of the view model is null.

Can some body please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're passing a `name` attribute that doesn't match the property name that you want to bind to. So it won't bind. You probably just want this:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Matched, true)
@Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Matched, false)
```

This will give you two radio buttons; one for `Matched = true` and one for `Matched = false`.

In the rendered markup, both radio buttons will already have the same name attribute since they are binding to the same field, meaning only one will be selectable at a time.

Comment: The way I am doing this, you will have a list of object displayed on the screen, and you will select one object( by using the radio button). So when user click on submit button, I go through the list and find the selected option. If I use RadioButtonfor and dont define name its allowing me to select multiple objects.

Comment: Then have a single string field that specifies the "object" and use that to determine what was selected. Then, give your radio buttons string values corresponding to each object. You need the fields to have the same name and you need that name to bind to a property, which means you can't use multiple properties without convoluted custom binding.

Answer (score 0):

I did this by using Jquery. I created another field in my view Model and populated this value in Jquery based on the selected radio button.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:radio[name=name1]").click(function (e) {       
    $("#SelectedSuppliedID").val(e.target.id);       
});
```

});

```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Matched, true, new { Name = "name1", id="Matched-"+Model.Id })
```